# Reading data in exponential format in python (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, exponential

I am trying to read the data but its first column have data in exp format which is not allowing me to read the file, here is the minimal working example of my code and here is the link [datafile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pbn6Ad5Ka-FzcMKBxkvYGoyNSYgSHQ-3) for trying out the code

```
import numpy as np
filename ="0 A.dat"
data = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',', skiprows=3)
```

but I am getting this error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float

Answer (score 0):

You can read them with pandas:

import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',', skiprows=3)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def yesfloat(string):
    """ True if given string is float else False"""
    try:
        return float(string)
    except ValueError:
        return False

data = []
with open('0 A.dat', 'r') as f:
    d = f.readlines()
    for i in d:
        k = i.rstrip().split(",")
        data.append([float(i) if yesfloat(i) else i for i in k]) 

data = np.array(data, dtype='O')
data
```

I don't know if that is the answer you are looking for but i tried it with you data and it returned this 
array([list(['% Version 1.00']), list(['%']),
       list(['%freq[Hz]\tTrc1_S21[dB]\tTrc2_S21[U]\tTrc3_S21[U]\tTrc4_S21[U]']),
       ...,
       list([9998199819.981998, -22.89936928953151, 0.07161954135843378, -0.0618770495057106, -0.03606368601322174, '']),
       list([9999099909.991, -22.91188769540125, 0.07151639513438152, -0.06464007496833801, -0.03059829212725163, '']),
       list([10000000000.0, -22.92596306398167, 0.07140059761720122, -0.0669037401676178, -0.02493862248957157, ''])],
      dtype=object)